# How to run a file in a separate directory? Bash

Tags: bash, shell

Quick question, how do I run a file in another directory using a bash script?

So far I have:

```
#!/bin/#!/usr/bin/env bash
counter=0
while [ "$counter" -le 208 ]
do
     mv $counter.txt /root/Assignment3_submission/query

     # MUST RUN THE FUNCTION HERE

     mv /root/Assignment3_submission/query/$counter.txt 
        /root/Assignment3_submission/data

((counter++))
done
```

My file path is:

```
Assignment3_submission
|
|--> data
|     |
|     L--> .txt files numbered 0-208
|     L--> generate_all_predictions.bash
|
|--> query
|--> movie_recommender
```

When I run ./movie_recommender in Assignment3_submission it works perfectly.
Also my script (generate_all_predictions.bash) moves all the text files from 
data to query and back perfectly.

I just need to run this movie_recommender file in the bash script which is located in /Assignment3_submission/data

EDIT: I tried this line to replace the #MUST RUN HERE and got 200+ seg faults

```
/root/Assignment3_submission/movie_recommender query/$counter.txt data/*
```

EDIT2: So apparently I was trying to run in the wrong directory.. But thanks for all the input guys, really learned a lot!!

Comment: issue `chmod +x scriptfile` and run as `./path/to/scriptfile`

Comment: Add the directory containing the program to `PATH`, usually this is done in a startup file like `.bash_profile`, e.g. `PATH=$PATH:full-directory-name`.   By the way, your `#!` line is most certainly wrong, and getting 200+ seg. faults is a bug in the program you are running, which should be reported to the developers.

Comment: see `-t` argument for `mv` command: `mv -t /path/to/target/dir path/to/files* ...`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a number of tangential problems with your script.

- Having files in `/root/` suggests you are running this as the `root` user. That's a major no-no. Either you don't need root privileges at all (in which case running as a regular user will be a very minor change) or you need to learn to separate privileged administrative tasks from your regular use of the system (in which case there will be a bit of a learning curve, but you will be grateful to yourself in the end).
- Hard-coding paths makes your script impossible to reuse. You should redesign it so it works regardless of which directory you're in, and regardless of where the data files it should operate on are. You could make it accept a path name argument, or simply operate in the current working directory on the assumption that the user who invokes it understands this convention.
- Your shebang line is *very* confused. The thing after `#!` should be the absolute path to an interpreter (or, as the case may be, to a program like `env` which figures out the absolute path to an interpreter for you).

Maybe something like this.

```
#!/bin/bash

test -d ./query && test -d ./data ||
{ echo "$0: ./query and ./data must exist" >&2
  exit 1; }

for((counter=0; counter <= 208; ++counter))
do
    mv ./data/"$counter.txt" ./query

    ./movie_recommender query/"$counter.txt" data/*

     mv ./query/"$counter.txt" ./data

done
```

Comment: Thanks for all the info!

Answer (score 0):

You can easily use

```
cd ..
  execute stuff
cd -
```

or even more generic (to also allow further nesting):

```
pushd ..
 execute stuff (even containing further pushd ... popd)
popd
```

Answer (score 0):

Use absolute address everywhere :

```
/root/Assignment3_submission/movie_recommender /root/Assignment3_submission/query/$counter.txt /root/Assignment3_submission/data/*
```

Answer (score 0):

`pushd` and `popd` (or `cd` and `cd -` for simple cases) are options, however, I mostly find that using a subshell is much easier:

```
(
  cd /path/to/run/stuff/in
  # stuff to do here
)
```

Once the subshell exits, the main shell is still in the original location. (It also means that if it is interrupted, the working directory doesn't change)

For this example:

```
#!/bin/bash
counter=0
while [ "$counter" -le 208 ]
do
     mv $counter.txt ~/Assignment3_submission/query

     # Stuff to do in other PWD
     (
         cd ~"/Assignment3_submission/query"
         tar czf ~/things_in_dir_using_relative_paths.tar.gz * # Sample command

     )

     mv ~/Assignment3_submission/query/$counter.txt 
        ~/Assignment3_submission/data

((counter++))
done
```